# Why does my cron job appear to do nothing?

Tags: cron

I wrote a groovy script to check a service and send email if it found a problem.  It works fine from the command line.  I've struggled with getting it to work properly from cron.

This is my current (edited) crontab:

```
MAILTO=myid@myhost.com
BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *   . $HOME/.bashrc;$HOME/bin/monitorDataSourceStatus.groovy >> $HOME/mDSS.out 2>&1
```

I don't think the Ubuntu cron uses the "BASH_ENV" variable, but I saw that mentioned in other "cron" references, so I thought I'd try it.  The MAILTO is also likely ignored, as I don't have an MTA installed.

I know the basic operation of cron is ok, because I get a syslog entry every five minutes as this specifies.  The last one looks like this:

```
Oct  2 09:30:01 hostname CRON[20268]: (myid) CMD (. $HOME/.bashrc;$HOME/bin/monitorDataSourceStatus.groovy >> $HOME/mDSS.out 2>&1)
Oct  2 09:30:01 hostname CRON[20267]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct  2 09:30:10 hostname crontab[20275]: (myid) LIST (myid)
```

However, I can tell from expected side effects that it doesn't seem like the script is executing.  I've enabled some print statements in the script, but the "mDSS.out" file hasn't been modified for several days now.

I don't know if it's practical to install a MTA.  I assume that's Mail Transfer Agent.

Answer (score 2):

The MTA message is because your script is producing output which cron normally sends an email for.

Replace your cron job with this:

```
MAILTO=myid@myhost.com
BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *   . $HOME/.bashrc;$HOME/bin/monitorDataSourceStatus.groovy > $HOME/mDSS.out 2>&1
```

You'll need to install an MTA like `sendmail` in order to get cron messages. (I changed the >> to a >).

Comment: ssmtp would be suitable for this situation, it may be less overkill than sendmail, postfix or exim.

Comment: Why do you think changing ">>" to ">" is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Installing ssmtp helped.  Once I was able to see the output, I discovered that my .bashrc/.bash_profile was misconfigured, which is why nothing showed up in the job output file.  I managed to fix that, and now my job is working fine.